# What is the 'double-dot' [eg. 5..toFixed()] I see in minified js?

Tags: javascript, minifiedjs

I'm working on a project where I need to deal with javacsript frameworks for work.  We have a parser that reads through them, but errors on lines with .. such as

```
1..toPrecision()
```

or

```
24..map(function(t){return 7..map(function(a){return e[a][t]})
```

It doesn't seem to understand the "..", and I don't either.  Why is this valid javascript?  How does mapping on a single number work? Eventually someone will fix the parser, but I'm looking for a temporary fix as to how I can edit the minified .js file to work. Is there another way to write something like 24..map()?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's kind of a funny situation. Numbers can have a value after the decimal point, right?

```js
console.log(1.2345); // for example
```

Well, it's also possible to write a number with a decimal point without any numbers following it.

```js
console.log(5.);
```

So the first dot is the decimal point. The second is the property accessor.

```js
console.log(5.                  .toString());
//           ^ decimal point    ^ property accessor
```

[The specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-literals-numeric-literals) defines decimal literals as:

> *DecimalIntegerLiteral* . *DecimalDigits* opt *ExponentPart* opt

where opt means optional.

Answer (score 4):

The first `.` is the decimal separator character. `1.` is a number.

The second `.` is the object property accessor. `someNumber.toPrecision` is a function.

Another way to write it would be to write the number with more significant figures:

```
1.0.toPrecision()
```

Comment: It's a short and _weird_ way of saying `1.0`. Is there any reason for it that you know of?

Comment: @George It's one byte shorter (we're talking _minified_). And, possibly, just because it _is_ weird (obfuscation).

Comment: @TripeHound I agree with the obfuscation but surely you could make it 2 bytes shorter by just writing `1`

Comment: @TripeHound — JavaScript doesn't have integers. It only has *Numbers*. `1.toPrecision()` throws a syntax error because the `.` is the decimal point, not the property accessor. You can't put a letter on the right hand side of a decimal point.